# Android: How to get GPS data without using a MapView?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to get GPS data without using map view.The code that I have below is from O'Rielly's Programming Android book and is supposed to work but is not. I am using an Android 2.2.1 phone and the app closes immediately after it starts.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tvLattitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLattitude);
    tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    tvLattitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
    tvLongitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));

    locListenD = new DispLocListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 30000L, 10.0f, locListenD);}

private class DispLocListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tvLattitude.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
        tvLongitude.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));}
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    lm.removeUpdates(locListenD);}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 30000L, 10.0f, locListenD);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to add the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

to your manifest?

Well, I set up a similar project and found a problem with your code: in onCreate you immediately try to set the location from previous locations (which on first run obviously wouldn't be available). I erased those lines and the code seems to run fine

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  tvLattitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLattitude);
  tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);

  lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  locListenD = new DispLocListener();
  lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 30000L, 10.0f, locListenD);
}
```

Comment: Yes.I had added these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateNearestLocation(location);
}

private boolean updateNearestLocation(Location lastKnownLocation) {

    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    LocationManager m_locationManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Could not find a location provider");
        return false;
    }
    if (lastKnownLocation == null) {

        lastKnownLocation = m_locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    } else {

        m_locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
        lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
    lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();

    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to display the data in two text views.The code that I tried is:tvLattitude .setText(Double.toString(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude())); tvLongitude.setText(Double.toString(lastKnownLocation .getLongitude()))     below the last if statement but does not display anything in the text views

Comment: Try Log.d("gps",Double.toString(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude())); first to see if your getting anything from the last known location.

Comment: Does not look like I am getting anything.

Comment: Okay that means you aren't getting the location data. Like DigCamara said make sure you have this inside of you manifest. In addition, in your settings make sure you have enable location. 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Yes I have added permissions and enabled location in my phone.BTW, where does the Log.d command go?..I put it in the last if statement.

Comment: tvLattitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
Log.d("latitude", Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));

Comment: take a look at my newest answer. I amended it because it seems you were asking for a known location without checking if you had one at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to turn on the locations in your phone's settings:

Settings --> Location and Security --> My Location

Also if you are using an emulator keep in mind it won't generate location data unless you do it manually through the DDMS.